# View the full file path in a Windows error dialog box

Tags: windows-7, path

Recently on a PC, upon logging in, a dialog box appears with an error about "some 64 bit file couldn't be opened in a 32 bit environment" or something similar, the message contents aren't super important. The main question is, the title of the dialog box was a very simplified pathname, but it was very long and mostly obscured. Is there a way to determine this full pathname from the dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a regular Windows message-box then Ctrl+C (while the box is active) will copy its contents to the clipboard as text, including the title. You can then run any text editor such as Notepad and Ctrl+V paste it to see the complete text.